# Definiteness of a symmetric matrix of order $3\times 3$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $a,b,c$ be three positive real numbers such that $b^{2}+c^{2}\lt a\lt 1$. Consider $3\times 3$ matrix$$A = \left[
\begin{matrix}
1 & b & c \\
b & a & 0 \\
c & 0 & 1  
\end{matrix}
\right]
$$

Is the matrix positive definite or not?

We know if the quadratic form of $A$ is positive definite then $A$ itself a positive definite. But how we can show that the quadratic form of $A$ ,say, $Q(x)$ is positive definite? Or any other way to show it?

Comment: Your title refers to a symmetric matrix, so is the "$c$" in the $A_{23}$ position supposed to be a zero?  Otherwise, the symmetry of $A$ is in doubt.

Comment: Sorry, it was a little mistake...Now it is edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that a symmetric matrix is positive definite if and only if the determinants of the upper-left submatrices are all positive. See [Sylvester's criterion](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion).

In particular, it is sufficient to check whether
$$
1 > 0\\
a - b^2 > 0\\
(a - b^2) - ac^2 > 0
$$

Comment: +1. I didn't knew this, and besides solving OP's problem, it is useful for something I'm studying now. Thanks

Comment: No problem. If you can find a copy of Horn and Johnson, the sections on Hermitian and Positive definite matrices have proven very useful in my experience.

Comment: All right! Thanks for the extra tip :)

Comment: @IvoTerek also: if you've taken multivariable calculus, an extension of this is where the max/min/saddle-point test comes from

Comment: That's interesting. I've only seen the standard argument using the Hessian along with Taylor expansion.

Comment: The usual argument is valid, but only tells you how things work near $f:\Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R$.  For $f:\Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R$, the Taylor expansion near a critical point is an approximation of the form
$$
f(x_0 + x) \approx f(x_0) + \frac 12 x^T H x
$$
where the Hessian $H$ is symmetric.  $x_0$ is a minimum when $H$ is positive definite, a maximum when $H$ is negative definite, and a saddle when $H$ is indefinite.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $A$ is positive definite if and only if its eigenvalues are (real and) positive. Remember that the eigenvalues are the roots of $\det(A - \lambda I) = 0$.

Comment: I know it..With the help of the given condition how we detect that the eigen values are positive??

Comment: See Omnomnomnom's answer. It solves your problem far more beautifully than anything I could suggest right now.